# When is the virtual dom rendered?

Tags: vue.js, virtual-dom

I'm having a hard time understanding a few reasons of the Virtual-DOM based design.

I think I have grasped the main concept but there is still a few dark areas.

Here what i've understood : in a web application structure around VueJs for example, instead of directly manipulating the DOM, which would result in too muche re-layout/re-paint processes and would be time consuming, the dev manipulates a model of the dom, the virtual dom.

The Virtual DOM is a tree-like data structure and does not render directly.Any modification is not time consuming at all. The data of the Virtual Dom is **then** applied to the real dom.

My question here is on the ***then***.

***How to know when to apply the changes of the virtual dom on the real dom?***

I think I've understood that a change in the dom is sometimes a "transitional state" change and that kind of change does not need to be rendered immediatly.

***How to decide which change is a "real" change that need to be displayed or which change is a "transitionnal state" change that does not need to be displayed ?***

Do you have an example of a "transitional state" change that does not need to be rendered?

If any change is applied, I can't see the performance earning of the virtual dom.

I sense there's something I've missed, but i can't put my finger on it. I thought one of you guys could help.